# Why do Aria and Suzu always play the drum and whistle?

Tags: seitokai-yakuindomo

When Shino explains the school's rules, Aria and Suzu always play a drum and whistle. Why is that? Is this a reference to anything? Or is it just a Seitokai Yakuindomo thing?

[image: subtitles: "article two, clause three!"]

Answer (score -1):

no reason. it's a direction.
The measure is "three-three-seven hand clap"(san-san-nana-byoushi in Japanese).
There is no element that indicates the relevance of this direction in "Seitokai Yakuindomo".

Comment: What do you mean by "direction"?

Comment: @nhahtdh Director found it funny. Or are you one of those people that think there is deeper meaning behind everything?

Comment: @Euphoric: To me, it's unclear what the word "direction" means in this answer (before I can even ponder about whether there is a deeper meaning in this). And I don't think this answer is talking about the director's direction.